# django template engine with error checking?

Tags: python, django, templates, exception

I have a Django application which uses the Django template system to generate its (non-HTML) output, in addition the the web UI. There's a set of pages where a user can create a template for a report, adding {{ }} tags for variable substitution, and an extra templatetag library to format things nicely.

However, the current way I'm doing this is just:

```
t = Template(component_template)
self.output_content = t.render(component_context)
```

Which uses the default web-output template engine. This has `string_if_invalid` set to `None`, and dire warnings in the manual about breaking the admin pages if you change it.

So if a user gets either a typo in a variable name in a tag, it is quietly ignored and makes it into the output. If they have a mangled tag, it actually kills the web app. I'm looking for a way to validate the template at edit-time, so that the user can be warned that changes are needed.

What I'm aiming for is something like compiler output:

```
unknown variable 'ffsdfd' on line 33 of template
template syntax error on line 22 of template
```

My first thought was to create a new template Engine() and use that for this one purpose, so I could spot a distinctive default `string_if_invalid` but that doesn't tell me anything *about* the missing/incorrect variable.

```
engine = Engine(string_if_invalid="!!MISSING_VARIABLE!!", dirs=settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'],
                context_processors=settings.TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'],
                app_dirs=settings.TEMPLATES[0]['APP_DIRS'])

t = Template(component_template, engine=engine)

try:
    self.output_content = t.render(component_context)
except TemplateSyntaxError:
    pass # do something useful here to collect error messages
```

The TemplateSyntaxError exception works, except I don't get any context information, like where the error actually is, and of course I only get the first failure. Looking in the django.template code, it looks like internally there is some sort of extended exception that has the line number and the token that caused it to choke, but it doesn't escape from the render() method.

So:

How can I provide useful error handling for errors in user-edited templates? Should I be doing this a different way altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I solve it myself using a custom class and `string_if_invalid`. It gets you the variable name, but I'm sure you can tweak it further to get additional context info.

Global settings.py example, should be easily adaptable to your inline example:

```
class InvalidTemplateVariable(str):
    def __mod__(self,other):
        from django.template.base import TemplateSyntaxError
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("Invalid variable : '%s'" % other)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [....],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'string_if_invalid': InvalidTemplateVariable("%s"),
            'context_processors': [
               ....
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

BTW, you can get additional info on how/why this works at the following  article (which I wrote)  http://www.webforefront.com/django/customizedjangotemplates.html#stringifinvaliderror

Comment: Aha! So actually the part I was missing was: "If string_if_invalid contains a '%s', the format marker will be replaced with the name of the invalid variable." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables)

(But the conversion from str to exception is nice!)